# Last None Blank DAX Measure

Tags: dax

I have the results as:

[image]

but need the results to appear as:

[image]

ie. where the last value with data will fill up the entire horizon for that year, each month defaulting to the last month with data.

Attempting to use the DAX as:

```
[Land Dev YTD]:= VAR LastNoneblankDate = CALCULATE(max('Date'[Date]),FILTER(Hyperion,[Land Dev] > 0)) return IF([Land Dev] = 0,CALCULATE([Land Dev],FILTER(ALL('Date'),'Date'[Date]=LastNoneblankDate)),[Land Dev])
```

Should in theory be sufficient, ie. supplant the result, where 0, to the value whereby the data is last present. However, the result is:

[image]

as it blows away all the other dates where there is not data.

How can I get this resolved?

Comment: There is a built-in `LASTNONBLANK()` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634247.aspx

Comment: That is specific to a row in a table, I need it for a measure. I think you answered another question I had, Want to start a chat?

Comment: No, that doesn't really help future users (this isn't a tech support site). If you edit your post to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can probably help though.

Comment: Thank you. What is noted above is the minimum example

Comment: It's certainly not complete or verifiable. I don't know what your underlying tables, relations, and measures are. You haven't given readers enough information to reproduce what you are showing.

Comment: @AlexisOlson, it is a generally straightforward tabular model design, just a date dimension connected to fact table

Comment: OK. Should be easy to make a minimal, complete, verifiable example then. I'm not going to guess at what your tables and measures look like with the limited context you've given. Post something easily reproducible and you are far more likely to get help.